# RSS Feed URL Validation in Java

Tags: java, validation, url, rss, feed

I need to check RSS feed URL validation. I have a url, now I need to check this url is only for RSS feed, how do I check that in core java? please help

Comment: You have no choice but to access that URL to check if it is actually an RSS feed... As to checking its shape, use `URI`.

Comment: yes, I think that is only the way

Answer (score 1):

I know it was 3 years ago), but here is my code.
Use the library of rome.
[Using ROME to read a syndication feed](https://rometools.github.io/rome/RssAndAtOMUtilitiEsROMEV0.5AndAboveTutorialsAndArticles/RssAndAtOMUtilitiEsROMEV0.5TutorialUsingROMEToReadASyndicationFeed.html)

```
public boolean romeLibraryExample(String address) {
    boolean ok = false;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
        SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(url));
        ok = true;
    } catch (Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ok;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a simple way, don't know how far it meets, but in my case it is helpful. Bellow is my code snippet

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(url); // url is your url for testing
doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("rss")
```

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use XML Validation for that:
Download XSD file from here and put it behind you class file:
http://europa.eu/rapid/conf/RSS20.xsd

You can use XSD with DOM:

```
private void validate(final File file) throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
    final List exceptions = new ArrayList();

    final ErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorHandler() {
        public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
            // we can forgive that!
        }

        public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
            exceptions.add(e);
        }

        public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
            exceptions.add(e);
        }
    };

    final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(false);
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    final Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Rss20.xsd"));

    factory.setSchema(schema);

    final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    builder.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

    builder.parse(file);

    if(exceptions.size() == 0) {
        // no error
    } else {
       // Error happens!
    }
}
```